Menu toggle icon in top navbar is not floating left
I have a Menu toggle icon in top Navbar which is refusing to float left.


header {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px rgb(0 0 0 /10%);
  background-color: #2980b9;
  transition: left 300ms;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: right;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #5499c7;
}

.dropdown a,
label {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  Padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #5499c7;
}

.dropdown a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-left: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dropdown label {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <label for="menu-toggle">
                <span class="las la-bars"></span>
            </label>

      <a href="#">
        <span class="las la-home"></span>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <span class="las la-envelope"></span>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <span class="las la-bell"></span>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <span class="las la-user"></span>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>



As you can see the picture below: (marked red arrow line)

I want all Navbar items float right except toggle-menu icon bar which is span Anyone can help i appreciate.
I tried floating left, but it refuses

You can add flex-gorw:1; on toggle btn.
.dropdown > *:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

Because you hava background color on label, I wrap label by span so the transparent span will fill the space.
<span>
    <label for="menu-toggle">
        <span class="las la-bars"></span>
    </label>
</span>



header {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px rgb(0 0 0 /10%);
  background-color: #2980b9;
  transition: left 300ms;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: right;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #5499c7;
}

.dropdown a,
label {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #5499c7;
}

.dropdown a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-left: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dropdown label {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown>*:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <span>
        <label for="menu-toggle"><span class="las la-bars"></span></label>
      </span>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="las la-home"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="las la-envelope"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="las la-bell"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="las la-user"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>




Thanks your point is good, but the whole label turns into a button which is not good so i nested the label into DIV, then the flex-gorw:1; will effect the DIV not the button.

I would suggest wrapping the a tags in a nav element, and using justify-content: space-between on .dropdown rather than justify-content: right


header {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px rgb(0 0 0 /10%);
  background-color: #2980b9;
  transition: left 300ms;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #5499c7;
}

.dropdown a,
label {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  Padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #5499c7;
}

.dropdown a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-left: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dropdown label {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown nav{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <label for="menu-toggle">
        <span class="las la-bars"></span>
      </label>

      <nav>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="las la-home"></span>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
          <span class="las la-envelope"></span>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
          <span class="las la-bell"></span>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
          <span class="las la-user"></span>
        </a>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>




Your solution is reasonable too.



header {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px rgb(0 0 0 /10%);
  background-color: #2980b9;
  transition: left 300ms;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #5499c7;
}

.dropdown div {
  display: flex;
}


.dropdown a,
  label {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  Padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #5499c7;
}

.dropdown a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-left: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dropdown label {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
<header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <label for="menu-toggle">
                <span class="las la-bars"></span>
            </label>
            
            <div>
              <a href="#">
                  <span class="las la-home"></span>
              </a>

              <a href="#">
                  <span class="las la-envelope"></span>
              </a>

              <a href="#">
                  <span class="las la-bell"></span>
              </a>

              <a href="#">
                  <span class="las la-user"></span>
              </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>



Have a lot of solutions to do it, this is a suggestion:
CSS
.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between; // <- added this
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #5499c7 ;
}

HTML
<div class="dropdown">
    <label for="menu-toggle">
        <span class="las la-bars"></span>
    </label>

    <div><!--Wrapped your menu link in a div-->
        <a href="#" >
            <span class="las la-home" ></span>
        </a>

        <a href="#" >
            <span class="las la-envelope" ></span>
        </a>

        <a href="#" >
            <span class="las la-bell" ></span>
        </a>

        <a href="#" >
            <span class="las la-user" ></span>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>

